# Stoping Macro if Connection is Lost

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, vba

I have a series of codes that run when designated, the first is a connection check. If it is successful then it allows the code to continue, if not it stops it altogether. I am worried however about what happens when the connection is lost after this process. There is data on a local table that is uploaded to our SQL server during this process, if the connection terminates mid download it looks like sometimes the data is still transferred but not if it happens right away.

The second part of the code, deletes all the local tables contents which contain employee information, then downloads the new data so if there were any updates the most recent information is provided.

I am trying to figure out if there is a method or code that can be implemented to tell the query to stop running as soon as connection is lost, or if there is a way to undo it if it happens.

Or would it be a good idea to combine the connection code with the upload and delete codes so it runs every time before it initiates a process?

The connection code that runs at the beginning is:

```
Public Function StartUp()
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim localrst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim remoterst As New ADODB.Recordset


On Error Resume Next
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection


cnn.Open "Provider=PRO; Data Source=SOURCE; Initial Catalog=CAT;" _
& "User Id=ID; Password=PW;"

If cnn.State = adStateOpen Then
  MsgBox ("You have an established connection with the L&TD SQL Server Database and the CDData table has been uploaded to the server.")
Else
MsgBox ("Cannot connect to SQL Server. Data will be stored locally to CDData Table until application is opened again with an established connection.")
End
End If

On Error GoTo 0

' MsgBox ("Please wait while the database is updating, this may take a moment.")

End Function
```

As you can see, I placed an END before the END IF so if there is no connection it just ends altogether.

The UPLOAD code is

```
Public Function Update()
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Dim err As DAO.Error

'    Const DestinationTableName = "AC_CDData"

Const ConnectionString = _
        "ODBC;" & _
            "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};" & _
            "Server=SERV;" & _
            "Database=DB;" & _
            "UID=ID;" & _
            "PWD=PWD;"
Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("")

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("CDData", dbOpenTable)

qdf.Connect = ConnectionString

Do While Not rs.EOF

    qdf.SQL = "INSERT INTO AC_CDData_1(EmployeeID, EmployeeName, Region, District, Function1, Gender, EEOC, Division, Center, MeetingReadinessLevel, ManagerReadinessLevel, EmployeeFeedback, DevelopmentForEmployee1, DevelopmentForEmployee2, DevelopmentForEmployee3, DevelopmentForEmployee4, DevelopmentForEmployee5, Justification, Notes, Changed, JobGroupCode, JobDesc, JobGroup) " & _
               "Values (" & _
               "'" & rs!EmployeeID & "', " & _
               "'" & rs!EmployeeName & "', " & _
               "'" & rs!Region & "', " & _
               "'" & rs!District & "', " & _
               "'" & rs!Function1 & "', " & _
               "'" & rs!Gender & "', " & _
               "'" & rs!EEOC & "', " & _
               "'" & rs!Division & "', " & _
               "'" & rs!Center & "', " & _
               "'" & rs!ManagerReadinessLevel & "', " & _
               "'" & rs!MeetingReadinessLevel & "', " & _
               "'" & rs!EmployeeFeedback & "', " & _
               "'" & rs!DevelopmentForEmployee1 & "', " & _
               "'" & rs!DevelopmentForEmployee2 & "', " & _
               "'" & rs!DevelopmentForEmployee3 & "', " & _
               "'" & rs!DevelopmentForEmployee4 & "', " & _
               "'" & rs!DevelopmentForEmployee5 & "', " & _
               "'" & rs!Justification & "', " & _
               "'" & rs!Notes & "', " & _
               "'" & rs!Changed & "', " & _
               "'" & rs!JobGroupCode & "', " & _
               "'" & rs!JobDesc & "', " & _
               "'" & rs!JobGroup & "')"


qdf.ReturnsRecords = False
On Error GoTo Update_qdfError
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
On Error GoTo 0

rs.MoveNext
Loop

rs.Close

Set qdf = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
Exit Function

Update_qdfError:
For Each err In DAO.Errors
    MsgBox err.Description, vbCritical, "Error " & err.Number
Next

End Function
```

So is there a way I can modify the Connection code and add it to the update code (minus the message boxes) so if the connection cuts off it will terminate the code?

Comment: You could trap the error, then retry the connection and resume - assuming you save the 'last successful key' of your input. Also, does this process take a long time? You may want to change over to 'rsOut.Addnew'... 'rsOut.Update'...

Comment: How would I trap the error, and it takes about 30 seconds to complete

Comment: Basically you add code that will send you to your special code (Error Trap) when any error occurs in the subroutine, then you can display the error and choose what to do next. I.e. you test for err.number = 6 and either fix the source/cause or ignore, or end. See this link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141571 or google for how to handle vba error

Answer (score 0):

Did you try out transactions? Wrapping your insert script inside a transaction will not change the database until you've explicitly committed the transaction. If the data connection is lost during the inserts, the commit will never be called, and the SQL Server data won't be changed.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196400%28v=office.15%29.aspx